# Oracle Spatial : Find the neighboring buildings

Tags: oracle, spatial

I'm creating an application which finds the neighboring buildings/ hydrants of a building on fire. I've created the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE building (
       buildingno VARCHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY
       , buildingname VARCHAR2(32),noofvertices INT
       , shape MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE hydrant (hydrantno VARCHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY
      , point MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE firebuilding(hydrantno VARCHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY)
```

I want to find the nearest neighbors of a particular building (both hydrants and buildings). Can I do this without creating a spatial index on the column name?

I am learning spatial querying and the dataset I'm working on is small (about 20 entries in each table and won't grow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a good reason not to create a spatial index?

If you do, and if the number of shapes is small, you might get acceptable results and performance with a "brute force" approach that uses `SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE` to calculate the distance between the given point and each of the other points points and then picks the smallest distance.  For example, if `firebuilding` identifies the given building, the following query identifies the closest building(s) using a tolerance of 1 metre (if the coordinates are geodetic) or 1 coordinate unit (if the coordinates are non-geodetic):

```
SELECT
    B.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            A.*,
            DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY A.DISTANCE) AS RANKING
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    OTHER_BUILDINGS.*,
                    SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE(BUILDING.SHAPE, OTHER_BUILDINGS.SHAPE, 1) DISTANCE
                FROM
                    FIREBUILDING,
                    BUILDING,
                    BUILDING OTHER_BUILDINGS
                WHERE
                    BUILDING.BUILDINGNO = FIREBUILDING.BUILDINGNO
                    AND
                    OTHER_BUILDINGS.BUILDINGNO <> BUILDING.BUILDINGNO
            ) A
    ) B
WHERE
    B.RANKING = 1;
```